# Short story. Madonna is the US president. Has gay and dystopian themes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

Supposedly read around the turn of the century in *Fantasy & Science Fiction*. (Not all recollections reliable, this is second-hand for an aging friend.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any extra info you could [edit] in or expand upon the details you already have? This is very terse at the moment

Comment: Not being a complete fool, I would have included all "extra info" at the beginning, had the friend provided any more.

I think that Madonna as the POTUS is a hint enough… unless, of course, the friend misremembers. (I googled, in vain.)

Comment: But perhaps you could get back to your friend and ask them for more story details? Does President Madonna play a big role in the story, or is she just a background detail? Is your friend 100% sure it was in *F&SF* and not a similar magazine such as *Asimov's*?

Comment: What made it a dystopia?

Comment: Of course I did at once, and there was NOTHING useful further. Madonna was supposed to be just one background detail. Quite sure. The general tenor; "taking place in a dystopian near future".

Elsewhere it has been suggested that this is most likely misremembered (no POTUS but the remaining two out of three) "Pervert" by Charles Coleman Finlay (_FSF_ March 2004, opening paragraphs and recording:  https://escapepod.org/2008/08/08/ep170-pervert/ )

I'll close this in a couple of days.

Comment: My understanding is one should not include necessary information only in the title. Consider putting the title information in the body.

Comment: I'm trying to get it clear in my head, is it the singer Madonna or the religious icon Madonna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely was misremembered "Pervert" by Charles Coleman Finlay (*FSF* March 2004, opening paragraphs and recording: https://escapepod.org/2008/08/08/ep170-pervert ). No Madonna/POTUS but the remaining two out of three.

Comment: Why do you think this is the answer? Madonna as POTUS was the only unique detail given in the question.

Comment: All the other hints fit (knowing the friend, I could assign especially high weight / a priori probability to the *FSF*). Sorry about the singer.